# How can I calculate the time it will take for a UIScrollView to end dragging?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Here's the delegate method I need to use:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

Here's what I've done (I'm only interested in the Y axis):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    CGFloat distanceY = targetContentOffset->y - scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat time = distanceY / velocity.y;
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working because the velocity is not measured in points.
It logs values between -5.0 and +5.0 but I just don't get it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I actually just played around with this exact question the other day. After some experimenting and playing with XY graphs in Excel, I came up with the following polynomial formula that generally gave a result that was pretty close.

```
NSTimeInterval scrollDuration = velocity.y * velocity.y * -0.0190848 + velocity.y * 0.30489632 + 2.098846;
```

This seems to work well for velocities of 0.5 or higher.

This also assumes the scroll view's `decelerationRate` is set to the default value of `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal`.